# $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $2^\alpha$, $3^\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, implies $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $2^\alpha$, $3^\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$. Does it implies that $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: False.  For instance, $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$, which is not in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Sorry i miss type R instead of N. Now the question is in the correct form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an open problem, as documented on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/17560

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is an open problem in mathematics; unfortunately I can't localize a source. (I've read it once on [*Math Overflow*](http://www.mathoverflow.net/), but I have a hard time tracking it down).

Comment: What does it mean $\log_{2\text{ or }3}n$? And if you mean that $\alpha=\log_2 n$ or $\alpha=\log_3n$, suppose the former, why is $3^\alpha$ a natural number?

Comment: I think the question means that $2^\alpha$ *and* $3^\alpha$ are integers. Eg. $\alpha = \log_2 5$ gives $2^\alpha = 5$, but $3^\alpha = 12.82...$ is not an integer.